# Unfortunately app has stopped in Android when try to implement RecylerView

Tags: java, android, material-design

I am following [slidenerd Material design tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/user/slidenerd)(Android RecyclerView Example  part1,2,3,4) & I am using real device to test my android application.I have successfully build navigation drawer & when I try to add RecylerView into it by adding adapter (ThalakazAdapter.java) , app unfortunately get stopped.

This is my NavigationDrawerFragment.java

```
package com.thaalakaz.nadeesha.materialdesignapp1;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "testpref";
    public static final String KAY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER ="user_learned_drawer";

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    private  ThalakazAdapter adapter;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private View containerView;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mUserLearnedDrawer=Boolean.valueOf(readFromPreferences(getActivity(),KAY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER,"false"));

        if (savedInstanceState != null){
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        adapter = new ThalakazAdapter(getActivity(),getData());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        return layout;
    }

    public static List<Information> getData(){

        List<Information> data = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] icons ={R.drawable.ic_m,R.drawable.ic_m1,R.drawable.ic_m2,R.drawable.ic_m3};
        String[] titles = {"Nadeesha","Thilakarathne","Semini","Roshani"};

        for (int  i=0;i<titles.length && i<icons.length;i++){
            Information current = new Information();
            current.iconId = icons[i];
            current.titlel = titles[i];
            data.add(current);
        }
        return  data;
    }
    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, final Toolbar toolbar) {

        containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(),drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close){
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
               if(!mUserLearnedDrawer){
                   mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                   saveToPreferences(getActivity(),KAY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER,mUserLearnedDrawer+"");
               }
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {

                if (slideOffset<0.6){
                    toolbar.setAlpha(1-slideOffset);
                }

            }

        };

        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && mFromSavedInstanceState){
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(containerView);
        }
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });
    }
    public static void saveToPreferences(Context context,String prferenceName,String preferenceValue){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(prferenceName,preferenceValue);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static String readFromPreferences(Context context,String prferenceName,String defaultValue){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(prferenceName,defaultValue);
    }
}
```

This is my Adapter  (ThalakazAdapter.java)

```
package com.thaalakaz.nadeesha.materialdesignapp1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by hp on 7/22/2015.
 */
public class ThalakazAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <ThalakazAdapter.myViewHolder>{

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Information> data = Collections.emptyList();

    public ThalakazAdapter(Context context, List<Information> data){

        inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
    }
    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
        myViewHolder holder = new  myViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(myViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Information current = data.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(current.titlel);
       holder.icon.setImageResource(current.iconId);
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return 0;
    }

    class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView icon;
        TextView title;
        public myViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listText);
            icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listIcon);

        }
    }
}
```

My information.java class

```
package com.thaalakaz.nadeesha.materialdesignapp1;

/**
 * Created by hp on 7/22/2015.
 */
public class Information {
    int iconId;
    String titlel;
}
```

You can view my entire project from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3VmCeqDC7SDcGNDRFdZNTNqenc/view?usp=sharing)

Logcat

```
07-21 22:32:07.101    7099-7099/com.thaalakaz.nadeesha.materialdesignapp1 D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
07-21 22:32:07.111    7099-7099/com.thaalakaz.nadeesha.materialdesignapp1 I/SystemProperties﹕ get key=ro.kernel.android.tracing
07-21 22:32:07.281    7099-7099/com.thaalakaz.nadeesha.materialdesignapp1 I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
07-21 22:32:07.281    7099-7099/com.thaalakaz.nadeesha.materialdesignapp1 W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 14685: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
07-21 22:32:07.281    7099-7099/com.thaalakaz.nadeesha.materialdesignapp1 D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
07-21 22:32:07.301    7099-7099/com.thaalakaz.nadeesha.materialdesignapp1 I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
07-21 22:32:07.301    7099-7099/com.thaalakaz.nadeesha.materialdesignapp1 W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 414: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
07-21 22:32:07.301    7099-7099/com.thaalakaz.nadeesha.materialdesignapp1 D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
07-21 22:32:07.311    7099-7099/com.thaalakaz.nadeesha.materialdesignapp1 I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
07-21 22:32:07.311    7099-7099/com.thaalakaz.nadeesha.materialdesignapp1 W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 436: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
07-21 22:32:07.311    7099-7099/com.thaalakaz.nadeesha.materialdesignapp1 D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
07-21 22:32:07.381    7099-7099/com.thaalakaz.nadeesha.materialdesignapp1 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-21 22:32:07.381    7099-7099/com.thaalakaz.nadeesha.materialdesignapp1 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41027208)
07-21 22:32:07.391    7099-7099/com.thaalakaz.nadeesha.materialdesignapp1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thaalakaz.nadeesha.materialdesignapp1/com.thaalakaz.nadeesha.materialdesignapp1.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.thaalakaz.nadeesha.materialdesignapp1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.thaalakaz.nadeesha.materialdesignapp1.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreateView(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:63)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:924)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1116)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1218)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2170)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:300)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:838)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:34)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:826)
            at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:668)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.thaalakaz.nadeesha.materialdesignapp1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

fragment_navigation_drawer.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#DADADA"
    tools:context="com.thaalakaz.nadeesha.materialdesignapp1.NavigationDrawerFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerDrawerImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FF6F00">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:src = "@drawable/dog"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please can you attach the logcat report..

Comment: `this.data = this.data;` is wrong. `getItemCount` shouldn't return `0`

Comment: @ShadowDroid I add the logcat report

Comment: post `fragment_navigation_drawer.xml`

Comment: @Blackbelt I edit the both errors you have shown.But it still doesn't work

Comment: @Blackbelt fragment_navigation_drawer.xml is added

Comment: Why did you wrap the ImageView inside of a LinearLayout? Also, have you added the RecyclerView dependency to your gradle file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your onCreateView your are looking for the wrong id. Change

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

with

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
```

I also noticed that in your `Adapter`'s constructor, you are assingn this.data to itself. Change

```
this.data = this.data;
```

to

```
this.data = data
```

and `getItemCount` shouldn't `return 0`, but the size of data (if it is not null)

Comment: Now app is working :) .I am a beginner.Thank u so much ,You save my time